# Installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools using this command

`Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` via PowerShell and this error was appearing to me
[image]

Note: I need to install this in my machine, not just in the project

Comment: That `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` package is just a nuget package, therefore it is not for machine-wide nuget installation. Basically, you can't install any nuget package for machine installation.

Comment: Ok, I understand, but do you know how can I install the .net Entity Framework on my machine? Because I looked for some help on the internet and they said that when run this command (dotnet ef) in CMD, it should appear a Unicorn to me... but having some trouble on it

Comment: And even if I try to install in my project, the same error appears

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the package manager source needs to be fixed. If you are using Visual Studio, navigate to **Tools >> Nuget Package Manager >> Package Manager Settings** and verify the package source.

[image]

Comment: @RavelSbrissaOkada: Try to run `Get-PackageSource` command on powershell to view the registered sources, and if nuget is not registered, please run the following command in regiter it - `Register-PackageSource -provider NuGet -name nugetRepository -location https://www.nuget.org/api/v2`